# Launching a DatePicker from edit text

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using Date picker on one of the **`edittext`**

**ID of edit text is** ::  **`android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"`**

**search_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"
            android:layout_width="258dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="selectDate" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2.5" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lunch" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Dinner" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="254dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include layout="@layout/screen_bottombar_photodesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SearchPage.java**

```
public class SearchPage extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);
    }

    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
        mEdit.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, dd, mm+1);
        }
    }

}
```

---

- When I click the edit text of
  `android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"` the date picker should launch
- but what's happening is wherever I click on the screen date picker
  is launching

**how to resolve this**

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
public class SearchPage extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;
    DialogFragment newFragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
        newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        mEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            }
        });
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
    }
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, dd, mm+1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey i tried the code ..... i get error as 10-05 09:28:02.974: E/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method selectDate(View) in the activity class com.project.findmybuffet.SearchPage for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Comment: Hey thanks again,,, but i have a meessage ...... Description Resource Path Location Type
The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String) SearchPage.java /FindMyBuffet/src/com/project/findmybuffet line 30 Java Problem