# DatePickerDialog in Android always shows the previously set date

Tags: android, date, calendar, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am doing the following in my app:

1.I have two `EditText` boxes.

2. On clicking each of them a `DatePickerDialog` pops up.
3. I set the date in the Datepicker.
4. On closing the dialog box the date gets set in the edittext.

The problem is as follows.

After setting the date in  the datepicker , the datepicker always shows the date I have set and not the current date. i.e. if I set the date as 2014-09-09 when I click the edittext again the date on the datepicker is shown as the above set date and not the present date.

Can anyone guide me how to fix this step by step..

My codes are as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.edt_date_from:
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt_date_to.getWindowToken(), 0);

        edt = 1;
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        break;
    case R.id.edt_date_to:
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        edt = 2;

        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        break;
}



   @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        int iDay,
        iMonth,
        iYear;

        iDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        iMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        iYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener,
                iYear, iMonth, iDay);
        dp.updateDate(iYear, iMonth, iDay);

        return dp;

    }

    return null;

}




  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        years = year;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;

        updateDisplay();

    }

};

public void updateDisplay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (edt == 1) {
        date_frm.setText(new StringBuilder()

        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
                .append(years).append(" "));
    } else {
        edt_date_to.setText(new StringBuilder()

        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
                .append(years).append(" "));
    }
}
```

Comment: where you pass EditText date value to Date Dialog ?

Comment: din get wat u wanna say

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193349/launching-a-datepicker-from-edit-text/19193772#19193772

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog(int,%20android.os.Bundle)):

> A call to onCreateDialog(int, Bundle) will be made with the same id the first time this is called for a given id. From thereafter, the dialog will be automatically saved and restored.

If you insist on using these deprecated activity-managed dialogs and not `DialogFragment`s, move the init code that resets the date to [`onPrepareDialog()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog(int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle)).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **`onCreateDialog()`** method in your activity

just add a onClick listener to your edit text and in the onClick method have this code

**`showDialog(999);`**

Then

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == 999) {
        Date date = new Date();
        int year=date.getYear();
        int month=date.getMonth();
        int day=date.getDay();
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}
```

it will do the job...

Comment: I want to reset my datepicker dialog to the current date i.e today's date and not to the date set on the edittext.

Comment: This will do the trick try it...         It only sets the current date to the date picker not the edit text